# Field Weights - Charge

Tags: force-fields

I was just wondering what this charge function controlled. When I changed it from 1 to 0 I did not see any apparent changes in my animation. Just curious and want to know how I could use it for future projects. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A [charge force field](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.1/physics/forces/force_fields/types/charge.html) can work like honey or a magnet, as particles move close to it, they slow down or stick to it depending on the settings, with two opposing fields (one on the particle system) you can get a magnetic result that draws the particles to the force field.

Note that gravity overpowers a charge, so you should set gravity to 0.0 to see the effect.

The charge setting in the particles field weights defines whether a particle sticks to the charge field, as you increase it particles passing through the charge field will start to stick.

By also having a charge field on the particle emitter you can use positive and negative values to have the particles drawn to or repelled from the field, like magnets.

Comment: Here is the updated version of the link you shared, detailing the "charge" function in Blender 3.1: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/forces/force_fields/types/charge.html